# Input/Output Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A have an `index.html.erb` page with selection of two options ("First", "Second") and three different textfields, in which may be inputed `a, b, c` values. `c` is needed only when "Second" option is selected.

Then I have to perform a method, depending on which option is chosen: if it is the "First", i give to it my `a, b` and get one result, if it is "Second", then give `a, b, c` and proceed it to another method.

I already have:

*app/views/welcome/index.html.erb*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainbox">
        <%= form_for(@data_lab) do |f| %>

        <%= options_for_select(disabled: "Select an option", ["First", "Second"]) %>

        <%= text_field(:a_value, class: "text_in") %>
        <%= text_field(:b_value, class: "text_in") %>
        <!-- Appears only when "Second" option is selected: -->
        <%= text_field(:c_value, class: "text_in") %>

        <%= f.submit %>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</body>
```

*app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb*

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  include WelcomeHelper
  require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/concerns/DataLab.rb"
  def index; end
  def welcome
    @data_lab = DataLab.new
    @data_lab = params(data_params)
  end
end
```

*app/models/concerns/DataLab.rb*

```
class DataLab < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :a_value, :b_value, :c_value
end
```

*app/helpers/welcome_helper.rb*

```
module WelcomeHelper
  def data_params
    params_require(:data).permit(:a_value, :b_value, :c_value)
  end
end
```

I've got stacked on `Could not find table 'data_labs'` error, but, I guess, I need to create a database for my data_lab class.

How can I perform input/output correctly? How can I handle methods depending on my `options_for_select`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `DataLab` inherits `ApplicationRecord` so there must be a db table for this class.

For the third textfield, you can assign an `id` or `class` attribute to `options_for_select` and use JS to monitor changes on it and on the basis of the selected option show or hide the textfield.